# Regex \b followed by symbol in Keyboard Maestro

Tags: regex, keyboard-maestro

I'm sure there's a really simple answer to this, but I can't find it!

In Keyboard Maestro, I'm trying to set the trigger as a regular expression of semicolon followed by one of a few characters, like this:

```
;[.,\s]
```

When I put it like that, it works, but I only want the trigger to fire when the semicolon is on its own (at the beginning of a sentence, or after a space). I would think this would do the trick:

```
\b;[,.\s]
```

...but when I put the boundary character in, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

(I should add that the boundary character works fine when followed by an alphanumeric character, so it seems to just be an issue with symbols)

Comment: Do you have sample input/output that we can test this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the opposite construct as there is no word boundary between a space or start of string and a semi-colon:

```
\B;[,.\s]
^^
```

Here, `\B` is a non-word boundary that matches at all the locations where a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) does not match. In this specific case, `;` will be matches *only* at the start of the string *or* if preceded with a non-word char (any char other than a letter/digit/`_` and, depending on the regex library, other (very rare) chars that are consider "word" chars.

Comment: @CaseOfTheMondays Glad it did, please also consider [upvoting the answer if it turned out useful for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)